# XSLT: How to delete one attribute in certain children

Tags: xslt, nodes

I have Googled quite a bit, and can't figure out how to delete a particular attribute in a particular child node.   In this example, I want to delete the "name" attribute, but only when under "alternate" parent items - not anywhere else.  In this example, keep the "name" attribute under reference for example, but remove the ones under alternate.....

Start with this XML

```
    <products>
<product id="123456">
   <alternate-products>
      <alternate>
         <number>2002</number>
         <name>2002</name>            <-- want to remove this one
      </alternate>
      <alternate>
         <number>2002</number>
         <name>2002</name>            <--- remove this one too
      </alternate>
   </alternate-products>
   <references>
      <reference>
         <name>2002</name>           <-- keep this one - not under alternate
         <date>2002</date>
      </reference>
   </references>   
</products>
```

Desired XML:

```
<products>
   <product id="123456">
   <alternate-products>
      <alternate>
         <number>2002</number>
      </alternate>
      <alternate>
         <number>2002</number>
      </alternate>
   </alternate-products>
   <references>
      <reference>
         <name>2002</name>           <-- still there - good!
         <date>2002</date>
      </reference>
   </references>   
</products>
```

Can anyone provide some tips??

Comment: Terminology is important:`name` in your XML is an *element*, not an *attribute*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <!-- Identity Transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="alternate/name"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This does not do what OP asked for - and the result is "correct" only by coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that.

Comment: Why don't you delete your answer instead of copying mine.

Comment: @michael.hor257k that is just a conincident when i edit xpath, as per your comment, you can see in edit change that only in xpath.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to delete the "name" <strike>attribute</strike> element, but only when under "alternate"
>   parent items - not anywhere else.

Easy to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="alternate/name"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This did the trick.  Thanks to both you and Rupesh below for this answer!   <xsl:template match="alternate/name"/>